# Pointers to objects in C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I am trying to get the hang of C++ pointers and objects, through a small project implementing a simple Vehicle Routing Problem. Even though my code is currently working, I can't shake the feeling that my approach is completely wrong. What bugs me, are snippets of code such as :

```
std::map<const Route*, double>::iterator it = quantities.begin();
if ((*(*(it->first)).getDestination()).getDemand() > (*(*(it->first)).getDeparture()).getSupply())
```

The pointer hell situation in the if condition is the result of the get methods returning pointers to already created objects. The methods being called are :

```
const Departure* Route::getDeparture() const {
    return departure;
};

const Destination* Route::getDestination() const {
    return destination;
};
```

and

```
int Destination::getDemand() const {
    return demand;
};

int Departure::getSupply() const {
    return supply;
};
```

Am I completely off track here, am i missing something or is this type of situtation something normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase readability you can change `*`s to `->`:

```
if(it->first->getDestination()->getDemand() > it->first->getDeparture()->getSupply())
```

Also, **if you aren't going to give up ownership of that object** (and you aren't, in this case) it is better to return by `const` reference:

```
const Departure& Route::getDeparture() const {
  return *departure;
};
```

and use `.`, not `->`:

```
if(it->first->getDestination().getDemand() > it->first->getDeparture().getSupply())
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `(*p).x` write `p->x`.

Comment: and just chain as iterator->member->method1->method2 etcetera?